# transfer change history from Subversion to TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I have a application in Subversion and I want to migrate it to TFS with all the history records. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the [TFS Integration Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb840033.aspx) (last I checked it did require a good deal of setup and scripting), or a commercial tool (such as [this](http://www.timelymigration.com/home.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I'll second what  @driis said.  You basically have to iterate through the history of each file in the source system, then do an add + checkin of each file.  Depending on the size of your old source repository, and the amount of history, this can be daunting.

We used the TFS Integration platform when we migrated from StarTeam, and made a conscious decision to migrate tip revision only.  The migration of tip took on average 24 hours each time we ran it.  We also ran into a number of encoding issues and missed files that needed to be resolved during the migration process.

If you have a lot of source, My advice would be to figure out a point in time of history that you want to migrate from, and ignore all history prior to that point, unless you have regulatory reasons for maintaining that history back to the beginning.